# Auth0 - How to use mongoDB on localhost with Auth0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, auth0

I created a new database connection on Auth0, called local-mongo and I'm trying to use the Create script in order to create a user on my local mongoDB but I keep getting this Socket Hang Up error:

```
[Error] Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:211:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:303:23)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
```

The Create script template on Auth0 is as follows:

```
function create (user, callback) {
   mongo('mongodb://localhost:27107.com/my-db', function (db) {
   var users = db.collection('users');

   users.findOne({ email: user.email }, function (err, withSameMail) {

  if (err) return callback(err);
  if (withSameMail) return callback(new Error('the user already exists'));

  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
    if (err) { return callback(err); }
    user.password = hash;
    users.insert(user, function (err, inserted) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      callback(null);
    });
  });
});
});
}
```

Do I need an ngrok in order to connect to the local DB or is there another way I'm missing here ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On basis the above script works, and your question is how to connect with localhost then the answer is yes.

You might just wish to use a mongo cloud service provider if that suits your situation since then you will automatically have cloud access. Or just install on an Amazon EC2 instance and set up security group to allow access on the required port etc.

But yes, fundamentally these are your options. There needs to be a network connection to your database server. Another method is to put an API between your Custom DB Script and the backend DB.

For an example of a Node.js sample that does this see here:

[node api sample](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-node-api-sample)

and for custom DB scripts see here:

[postgres custom db scripts](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-github-source-control/tree/master/database-connections/postgresdb)

You could modify the above to use mongo instead. Just an idea only.

Comment: Gah, I don't know how it didn't cross my mind to just test it with mlab for example. Works just fine when using that. I'll try the other method as well with an API between. My app is made with React and Express so I think your suggestion should work just fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Good to hear! Thank you for acknowledging the answer :)